# ¿Cómo detectar mayúsculas y minúsculas?

Tags: javascript

```
  $("#clie").keyup(function () {

            var busqueda = $("#clie").val();
            if(busqueda.length >= 2){ //si la busqueda es menor a dos no busca nada
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "<?php  echo base_url(); ?>contacto/GetCliente",
                        data: {
                            keycliente: $("#clie").val()
                        },
```

Comment: ¿Necesitas detectar mayúsculas y minusculas de un input? Vamos amigo, tu código no está bien formateado y nos hablas poco de tu intento de resolverlo

Comment: Perfecto el título, ¿y la descripción? ¿y la pregunta?

Answer (score 6):

Creo que nos hablas poco de tu problema, pero basandome en el título. Puedes intentar con funciones como estas:

```
function esMayuscula(letra)
{
    return letra === letra.toUpperCase();
}

function esMinuscula(letra)
{
    return letra === letra.toLowerCase();
}
```

Y luego, si necesitas validar todas las mayusculas de algun input podrias hacer algo como

```
var miPalabra = "Arbol";
for(var index = 0; index < miPalabra.length; index++)
{
    var letraActual = miPalabra.charAt(index);
    if(esMayuscula(letraActual))
    {
        alert("La letra " + letraActual + " es mayúscula");
    }

    if(esMinuscula(letraActual))
    {
        alert("La letra " + letraActual + " es minúscula");
    }       
}
```